# How to only slide down current element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML.

```
<div id="myid">
   <ul class="someclass">
      <li class="static">
         <a href="#"><span>Page1</span></a>
         <ul class="someclass">
            <li class="static"><a href="page1a.php"><span>Page1A</span></a></li>
            <li class="static"><a href="page1b.php"><span>Page1B</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static">
         <a href="#"><span>Page2</span></a>
         <ul class="someclass">
            <li class="static"><a href="page2a.php"><span>Page2A</span></a></li>
            <li class="static"><a href="page2b.php"><span>Page2B</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Using the following code I am trying to expand and collapse based on link clicked by user. So if user clicks on "Page1" then it will expand (or collapse if it is already expanded) it and show Page1A and Pag1B. Similarly clicking on Page2 will have same effect. But when I use following code it expands and collapse all elements on page and not the current one which I clicked upon.

```
$('#myid > ul > li > a').click(function()
{
   if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").is(':visible') == false)
      $('#myid > ul > li > ul').slideDown('normal');
   else
      $('#myid > ul > li > ul').slideUp('normal');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need $(this)...

```
$(this).next('ul').slideDown('normal');
```

instead of

```
$('#myid > ul > li > ul').slideDown('normal');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` is the next sibling of the clicked anchor element, also you can use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) instead of the if condition

```
$('#myid > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    var $ul = $(this).next('ul');
    $ul.stop(true, true).slideToggle('normal');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this).next()` from jQuery, but you can simplify this a lot more, and structure it like this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myid">
    <span>Question?</span>
    <div class="toggle">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore
        magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight:700;
}
.toggle {
    display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myid span').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```
$('#myid > ul > li').find('> a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings('ul').stop().slideToggle('normal');
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bhxy/)

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
$('#myid > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("li").children("ul").slideToggle("normal");
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/B8XUe/)

Answer (score 0):

you can done by the below code:

```
 $('#myid > ul > li > a').click(function()
{
  if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").is(':visible') == false)
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown('normal');
  else
    $(this).next('ul').slideUp('normal');
});
```